# Как реализовать блок необычной формы?

Tags: css3

[image: блок]

Подскажите, как можно реализовать такой блок?

Comment: я не силен в css но кажется отсюда можно взять идею и немного изменить под себя https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/

Comment: А как Этот блок можно охарактеризовать? (кроме как фото показать) Что в нем особенное?

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: tomato;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div::before,
div::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
}

div::before {
  clip-path: ellipse(50% 50% at 50% 0%);
}

div::after {
 clip-path: ellipse(50% 50% at 50% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: tomato;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div::before,
div::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 5vh;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
}

div::before {
  border-radius: 0% 0% 50% 50% / 0% 0% 100% 100%;
}

div::after {
 border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 100% 100% 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: `clip-path` - хорошая штука, но пока её опасно использовать, за ответ +